# Find these prime numbers $p, q$?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

Let $p, q$ be prime numbers such that

$p = 3p_1 + 2; q = 3q_1 + 2$;

$p + q + 3$ and $3p + 3q + pq + 3$ are square numbers.

Find $p, q$?

P.S. I don't have any ideas about this problem :(

Thanks :)

Comment: Any specific constraints for $p_1$ and $q_1$?

Comment: Actually, it just uses to know that $p,q$ are not $3k$ or $3k+1$

Comment: Interesting question. I have written a program to solve the problem, and seems to me that the only solution is $p = 2, q = 11$ (or $p = 11, q = 2$). If the condition is relaxed such that $p$ and $q$ are just positive integers instead of prime numbers, there can be many solutions. However, from the observation of the solutions in the relaxed question, only one of $p$ and $q$ is an odd number. So, going back to the original question, if there exists any solution, one of $p$ or $q$ has to be $2$. I wonder if this observation helps to solve the problem without brute force trial-and-error.

Comment: @LaBird Thank you very much for the observation, it helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The only solutions for $(p,q)$ are $(11,2)$ and $(2,11)$.

The equation $3p + 3q + pq + 3 = k^2$ is equivalent to $(p+3)(q+3) = k^2 + 6$. Following the observation that $(p,q) = (2,2)$ is not a solution, one of $p,q$ must be odd. It follows that $k$ is even and $k^2 + 6$ has only one factor $2$, so the other prime must be even, i.e. equal to $2$.

Without loss of generality, let $q = 2$. We have to find primes $p$ such that $p + 5 = l^2$ and $5p + 9 = k^2$. The second equation can be factored as $(k+3)(k-3) = 5p$, and it easily follows that $p = 11$ is the only solution.

Interestingly, the conditions that $p+q+3$ is a square and that $p,q$ are $2 \mod 3$ were not even needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Fermat: It is explained in the second paragraph. For odd integer $k$, $k^2$ is odd and hence $k^2 + 6$ is also odd. For even integer $k$, $k^2$ is even and divisible by $4$, while $k^2 + 6$ is even but not divisible by $4$. So $k^2 + 6$ has only one factor $2$, meaning exactly one of $(p+3)$ or $(q+3)$ is even. So it follows that exactly one of $p$ or $q$ is even.

Comment: @Arthur: Very nice proof! Still at the end, we need to check the solution against those "unused" conditions: If any of them cannot be satisfied, then no solution would exist.